# Cannot call 'crossover' with arguments (series[float], hline); available overloads: crossover(series[float], series[float]) => series[bool]

Tags: pine-script

Trying to develop a strategy, but i am stuck here. I am a newbie. can anyone please help me to solve it. Thanks

```
//@version=4
study(" RSI", overlay=false) 
rsiinput = input(14,title="RSI_period", type=input.integer)
ma = input(20,title="ma", type=input.integer)
rsi=rsi(close,rsiinput)
basis = ema(rsi,ma)
plot(rsi, transp=0, title="rsi line", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(basis, title="ma", color=color.red, transp=0, linewidth=2)
f = hline(50, color=#03bbd5, linestyle=plot.style_line, linewidth=3, title="50")
crossover =  crossover(basis,f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argement "f" is not a series. To work around the error, you can simply replace "f" with "50".

```
crossover =  crossover(basis, 50)
```

Happy New Year!

Comment: Thanks a lot and Happy New Year :)

Comment: i am getting "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function" when i am trying to use resolution. can you please help me to solve it?

Comment: give a link to your question

Comment: thanks a lot bro, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061978/need-help-to-use-resolution